# meaning of scen$i in shell script

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh
export CLASSPATH=.

for i in "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
do
echo "running simulation $i..."

cd /home/acharya/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/
./ns /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/wrls.tcl
mv conf-out-tdsr.tr /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/parser
mv monitorlog.txt /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/parser/r2/evil$2/scen$i
mv reputationlog.txt /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/parser/evil$2/scen$i
mv pathmanagerlog.txt /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/parser/r2/evil$2/scen$i
mv misbehavenodeslog.txt /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/parser/r2/evil$2/scen$i
cd /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/parser/
java DSRParser trace conf-out-tdsr.tr $1 $2 > r2/evil$2/scen$i/scen-r2-$i.txt
java DSRParser routestats r2/evil$2/scen$i/pathmanagerlog.txt $1 $2 >> r2/evil$2/scen$i/scen-r2-$i.txt
cd ..done
```

Here is the second script-:

```
#!/bin/sh
export CLASSPATH=.
#./run1.sh
for i in "0" "10" "20" "30" "40"   
do   
    echo "Simulating evil node no. $i ..."
    cp /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/hdr_confidant.hevil$i /home/acharya/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/dsr/hdr_confidant.h
    cd /home/acharya/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35
    rm dsr/*.o
    make
    cd /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/
    ./run.sh 50 $i
done
```

These are two shell scripts i want to know about the meaning of.

```
mv monitorlog.txt /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/parser/r2/evil$2/scen$i
```

about the `scen$i` used.
`cp /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/hdr_confidant.hevil$i`  as the filename is only hdr_confidant.h but `evil$i` is used with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first script runs five times, the variable i is assigned to each value in the "1 2 3 4 5" list. For each loop iteration a set of files are moved. `scen$1` will be scen1, scen2, scen3... as i changes. two java programs are executed, the output files use the `$i` value so that each set of results is written to a different directory.

The second script is similar. The loop variable will be assigned to 10, 20, 30 etc.

$1 is the first parameter to any script. 
$2 is the second parameter.

To create a directory that does not exist insert this inside the loop at the top of the loop-:

```
 [ -d /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/parser/r2/evil$2 ] || mkdir /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/parser/r2/evil$2
```

Comment: These are the errors i am getting cp: cannot stat /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/hdr_confidant.hevil0': No such file or directory mv: cannot stat conf-out-tdsr.tr': No such file or directory mv: cannot stat monitorlog.txt': No such file or directory mv: cannot stat reputationlog.txt': No such file or directory ./run.sh: 15: ./run.sh: cannot create r2/evil0/scen1/scen-r2-1.txt: Directory nonexistent ./run.sh: 15: ./run.sh: java: not found

Comment: The directories the files are being moved to do not exist. You will have to create the necessary directories by modifying the script.

Comment: But what is the meaning of r2/evil0/scen$i  $i- is used what is this meant for? Is it supposed to create directories by itself because what if we passed more values for i so we have to create more by ourself? Instead i think it is supposed to create it by itself

Comment: It's just the path to the output text file from the java program.

Comment: I know that it is output but are we supposed to create these directories by ourself for i = 0 10 20 30 what if i is upto 1000

Comment: That's why it's best to check in the script loop if the directory exists - and if it does not then create it.

Comment: yes it is done manually but what if if we want to create it automatically using script

Comment: Then inside the loop check if the directory exists and if it does not exist then create it.

Comment: yes i have created it manually but ihow to do automatically using script

Comment: I've updated the answer with a solution to the automated approach.

Comment: If that has answered your questions you could kindly upvote the answer - many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The $i will be substituted with the value of i that is 1/2/3/4/5 or 10/20/30/40/50.
For example when the value of i is 1 and second argument is 2

mv monitorlog.txt /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/parser/r2/evil$2/scen$i 
becomes
mv monitorlog.txt /home/acharya/Desktop/xx/parser/r2/evil2/scen1

and $2 is the second argument to the script.

Comment: These are the errors i am getting                                  cp: cannot stat `/home/acharya/Desktop/xx/hdr_confidant.hevil0': No such file or directory                                              mv: cannot stat `conf-out-tdsr.tr': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `monitorlog.txt': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `reputationlog.txt': No such file or directory

./run.sh: 15: ./run.sh: cannot create r2/evil0/scen1/scen-r2-1.txt: Directory nonexistent
./run.sh: 15: ./run.sh: java: not found